Call macro on a separate sheet
I have a macro that works, called Saveaspdfandsend, which is on a worksheet called "Summary by S ref".
I am trying to call Saveaspdfandsend with a button on a worksheet called "Summary".
It does not like this line:
xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

The full code:
Sub Macro999()

Call Saveaspdfandsend

End Sub

Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20230130
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet

xFolder = "H:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\" + Range("N1") + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
"    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    
    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .To = "my email"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = Range("N1") + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
           .Send
End With
Else
MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub


Not surprising that ActiveSheet in Set xSht = ActiveSheet uses the active sheet.

As stated above, it works on the Active Sheet. Range("N1") refers the active sheet, too. I  would suggest to make the called Sub having the sheet object as parameter: Sub Saveaspdfandsend(xSht As Worksheet). Then comment Dim xSht As Worksheet and Set xSht = ActiveSheet. Take also care to use xSht.Range("N1") to build zFolder. Than, call it Saveaspdfandsend(Worksheets("YourNeededSheet"). Or Saveaspdfandsend(Me) from the sheet module where the Sub exists. Or (not using Call) Saveaspdfandsend Worksheets("YourNeededSheet")...

thanks FaneDuru, as I am a relative beginner with VBA would it be possible for you to add those amendments into the code for me and repost the update code if that would be ok?

I did not understand your comment (not edited), but I deduced what you want saying... Please, try understanding it (it is easy), test the suggestion and send some feedback. Now I have to leave my office...

I could not understand very well your comment, but I will try showing what I wanted suggesting in mine:
The updated Sub must look as:
Sub Saveaspdfandsend(xSht As Worksheet)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20230130
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

xFolder = "H:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\" + xSht.Range("N1") + ".pdf"
' Your existing code, as it is.
'.....
End Sub

Now, instead of calling as Call Saveaspdfandsend, use the next way (without Call):
 Saveaspdfandsend Worksheets("theNecessarySheetName")

Or calling from the sheet code module where the sub is:
 Saveaspdfandsend  Me


@Croon Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested approach? If tested, didn't it do what you need. Is it still something you do not understand?

Hi @FaneDuru thanks for your reply. I could not get it to work.
As I said the sheet I want the new macro in (with the button) is "Summary" and the sheet where the macro is currently recorded is "summary by S ref".
Would you be able to post the full code for the new macro that will work based on those sheet names?
As I say the original macro in the "summary by S ref" sheet works.
Thanks

It was this line of code it did not like (this is the Pivot table which the "print as PDF" picks up and prints and saves as).
xSht.PageSetup.PrintArea = xSht.PivotTables("FinalPivot").TableRange2.Address

@Croon If you are not able to copy your existing code from the line I show above I am afraid you cannot be helped... You do not make any effort to try understanding anything, you want code to do the job. This is not a way to be appreciated in our community...

Change
Set xSht = ActiveSheet

to
Set xSht = WorkSheets("Summary by S ref")

Personally, I almost never use ActiveSheet, ActiveCell or ActiveWorkbook.  I explicitly assign these values to variables that I control
